# Meteor call to Intrinio API returns data:null

Tags: http, meteor

Does anyone have an example of a call to the Intrinio financial data API?  I am trying to reconcile [their instructions](https://intrinio.com/tutorial/web_api) with this [Meteor Chef](https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/using-the-http-package) post but only getting halfway there.  I am able to access their data via browser and via command line but not through my code.  First time working with an API of any kind, appreciate any suggestions.

Also, I understand there is an [npm package for an Intrinio client](https://github.com/jspenc72/intrinio-client).  I'm on Meteor 1.2.1, not using npm.

I've added the `http` package and written the following in a client/lib file:

```
getData = function() {
    HTTP.call('GET','api.intrinio.com', {
        query: "/companies?ticker=AAPL",
        authorization: "myUsername:myPassword"
        },
        function( error, response ) {
            if(error) {
                console.log("Error")    
            } else {
            console.log(response)
            }
        });
    };
```

In the console, this returns the following - I'm getting the right status code but the data is empty:

```
Object {
    statusCode: 200,
    content: "<!DOCTYPE html>↵<html>↵<head>↵  <link rel="stylesh…pFinance</title>↵</head>↵<body>↵↵</body>↵</html>↵",
    headers: Object,
    data: null
}
```

The Intrinio instructions recommend the following, but this seems to conflict with the suggestion on how to write the call for Meteor:

```
var https = require("https");

var username = ""username";
var password = ""password";
var auth = "Basic " + new Buffer(username + ':' + password).toString('base64');

var request = https.request({
    method: "GET",
    host: "api.intrinio.com",
    path: "/companies?ticker=AAPL",
    headers: {
        "Authorization": auth
    }
}, function(response) {
    var json = "";
    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
        json += chunk;
    });
    response.on('end', function() {
        var company = JSON.parse(json);
        console.log(company);
    });
});

request.end();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Use the auth parameter (instead of authorization)

The query parameter must contain only query string parameters. /companies needs to be part of the URL.

Just to be safe, specify the https:// protocol in the URL.

```
HTTP.call('GET','https://api.intrinio.com/companies', {
  query: "ticker=AAPL",
  auth: "myUsername:myPassword"
},
function( error, response ) {
  if (error) {
    console.log("Error", error)    
  } else {
    console.log(response)
  }
});
```

Here is a link to the above code: https://github.com/intrinio/intrinio-meteor-example/blob/master/server/main.js

I hope this helps! By the way, I work for Intrinio. We offer free chat support if you need it in the future.